# Printing 2D lists

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

So I have a list which is defined as, for simplistic sake:

```
grid=[['X','X','O'],['X','O','X'],['O','X','X']]
```

I want to print this list but using `print(grid)` doesn't return it in any easily readable format.

Instead I want to print it in such a way it would look like:

```
X X O
X O X
X X O
```

I am very new to python and currently trying to learn how to code from the very basics. So I'm attempting define a function `print_grid()` such that it will print the grid in the easy to read format.

My start of the code is

```
def pinrt_grid(grid)
     for i in grid:
          print(i)
```

I am aware this will print each row, but each input of the grid is still shown as a string and isn't in the form I want it in. Can you suggest how I would go about getting it into this form?

Answer (score 2):

```
def print_grid(grid)
    for row in grid:
        print(' '.join(row))
```

Or even better, [pprint.pprint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html)

Answer (score 0):

This should work no matter how many items are present in the grid, as long as it is 2-dimensional.

```
grid=[['X','X','O'],['X','O','X'],['O','X','X']]
def print_grid(grid):
    for item in grid:
        line = ' '.join(item)
        print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `for` loop like below:

```py
for i in grid:
    print(' '.join(i))
```

In each iteration, `i` will be having the inner lists. As these inner lists are list of strings, you can use `join()` method to join the elements of list to for a string. The use `print()` to print the string.

Answer (score 0):

Only for fun, one line solution

```
grid=[['X','X','O'],['X','O','X'],['O','X','X']]
print("\n".join(map(" ".join,grid)))
```

you get,

```
X X O
X O X
O X X
```